# gcsfuse : connection to bucket drops and bucket has to be mounted again

Tags: gcsfuse

I am running gcsfuse on a GCE and mounted a GCS bucket correctly. I am running a python program that needs to access data from that bucket. To avoid interrupting the program when the GCE connection sometimes drops, I am using a screen, so that the program still runs when the connection drops.
However, sometimes (once a day more or less) when the connection drops, the connection to the bucket is lost for an unknown reason, so the program crashes. When I reconnect to the GCE, the bucket is not accessible anymore, and I have to mount the bucket again. Do you know how to prevent this ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand not every connection drop you are losing the bucket access, in some connection drops when you reconnect buckets are accessible, right? I couldn't reproduce the issue. I only lost the bucket access when the instance is restarted.

Why your GCE instance is dropping connection? Can you try to set [TCP keep-alive](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/general-tips#communicatewithinternet) to avoid disconnections?

Comment: Exactly, my connection often drops, but in most of the cases when I reconnect the program is still running thanks to the screen command which creates a detached screen session. However sometimes the bucket access is also lost and it crashes... Thanks for your answer, I will try TCP keep alive, might solve it !

Comment: @Leo did setting the TCP keep-alive help resolve the issue you were having?